# Del command in command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, delete-file, appdata

I want to, for example, delete a file in AppData/Roaming/MyFolder/myfile.txt.

I use command prompt and typed this: `del %userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/MyFolder/myfile.txt`

But then the command prompt said: `Parameter format not correct - "ppData"`

Then I think again and used `%appdata%` and typed:`del %appdata%/MyFolder/myfile.txt`

But the command prompt said: `Invalid switch - "MyFolder"`

How to delete myfile.txt using `%userprofile%` or `%appdata%`?
Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Try `del "%userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/MyFolder/myfile.txt"`

Comment: are quotes included?

Comment: yeah I was including quotes, though my comment wasn't quite right. Quotes are fine but  you should use backslash.  Quotes may not be necessary but if there was a space anywhere e.g. in the expansion of %userprofile% (which is unlikely) or if you had a space in the filename or anywhere in the path, then you'd need quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\` instead of `/` as the path separator:

```
del %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\MyFolder\myfile.txt
```

Comment: I think Windows allows /  so maybe his problem is as in my comment.. not using quotes.

Comment: @GregHewgill ah you're right.. I remember somebody once said it did..  I see it does when clicking the orb and typing in the search box to bring up an explorer window.  Though indeed, not in the command prompt

Comment: @barlop: `/` is usually permitted as a path separator when writing programs that directly call the Windows API functions. But even so, it's best to always use `\\` on Windows.

Comment: what if the folder has space?

Comment: @cromix: Well then you'd probably also want to use quotes. (Using quotes may also allow the use of `/`, I'm not certain.)

Comment: That's correct. Windows command prompt only supports double quotes.

Comment: Indeed the  quotes enable the use of forward slash, http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xkxNuMxE  well spotted @GregHewgill

Comment: @cromix  You need to use a double quote rather than a single quote and escape it in your code.I suppose Try replacing each of the single quotes with `\"`

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `%userprofile%` in the command:

```
%userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/MyFolder/myfile.txt
```

with your user account name. If it still does not work, try addressing the full path of the file you want to delete.

Comment: No that doesn't even work in the slightest  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aZntjX90  You are using forward slashes and single quotes neither of which are correct

Comment: @barlop ah that's right...thanks for the correction!

Comment: I didn't make the edit and the edit that "ohbewise" made is not really a correction because you still have forward slashes there. Try the command yourself you'll get the same error as the questioner got. If I could downvote you 3 times I would.  And a correct answer was posted before you, stating clearly to do backslash instead of forward slash. So even correcting your answer would be pointless because it just repeats what others have already said better in the same thread, before you.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
del /f /q “file_path”
```

Also, use backslashes in your file path.